# Read logs for multiple major versions ids?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

I'm trying to fetch logs (using LogService API Java SDK 1.7.0) for multiple major version ids.

Example: fetch logs for app versions 1 and 2:

```
...
logquery.majorVersionIds(Arrays.asList("1","2"));
ls.fetch(logquery);
...
```

but it throws this exception:

> com.google.appengine.api.log.InvalidRequestException: Exactly one major version id must be specified.
>       at com.google.appengine.api.log.LogServiceImpl$1.convertException(LogServiceImpl.java:108)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:106)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.log.LogServiceImpl.fetch(LogServiceImpl.java:31)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.log.LogServiceImpl.fetch(LogServiceImpl.java:22)

Am I doing something wrong or this is not supported? 
Java doc says:

> public LogQuery majorVersionIds(java.util.List<java.lang.String> versionIds)
>
> A setter that allows the user to specify the major app versions whose log data should be read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of the documentation. The error you are getting is telling you that only one version_id can be specified at the time. The [python docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logservice/functions) state that:

> Currently, you can specify only one version_id per fetch call.

In the future you can create an issue in the [external issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

ps: I filed an internal issue to fix this.